# Reduce data into nested categories

Tags: javascript, reduce

I am trying to reduce an array of data into a nested object. I almost have it except for the next items. Instead of pushing into the array it overwrites the entire array itself leaving only 1 value.

I am 100% sure the issue is with this line of code `[...(acc[t.sub_region] || []), t]` my gut is telling me I need to do something along the lines of `[...(acc[t.region][t.sub_region] || []), t]` however it is erroring out when I try this.

I posted a snippet below, as you can see SOUTH_EUROPE only has 1 item inside of its array when it should have 2.

**Desired Result**

```
const sorted = {
    EUROPE: {
        SOUTH_EUROPE: [{ item: 'Item 1' }, { item: 'Item 2' }],
        NORTH_EUROPE: [{ item: 'Item 3' }],
    },
    AMERICAS: {
        NORTH_AMERICA: [{ item: 'Item 4' }],
    },
}
```

```js
const items = [
    {
        region: 'EUROPE',
        sub_region: 'SOUTH_EUROPE',
        item: 'Item 1'
    },
    {
        region: 'EUROPE',
        sub_region: 'SOUTH_EUROPE',
        item: 'Item 2'
    },
    {
        region: 'EUROPE',
        sub_region: 'NORTH_EUROPE',
        item: 'Item 3'
    },
    {
        region: 'AMERICAS',
        sub_region: 'NORTH_AMERCA',
        item: 'Item 4'
    },
]

const sorted = items.reduce((acc, t) => {
    return {
        ...acc,
        [t.region]: {
            ...acc[t.region],
            [t.sub_region]: [...(acc[t.sub_region] || []), t],
        },
    }
}, {})

console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: If this is production code I would strongly suggest to use a loop instead. I believe this function will be pretty hard to debug/ maintain. Using simple for loop could take out some unnecessary complexity

Comment: @VincentMenzel I disagree with using loops vs reduce in this instance. I agree this could be confusing to someone who isnt familiar with reduce function but could be supported with a few lines of documentation. If you would like to show me a simpler solution using loops I would be glad to take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sub_region` is a nested property, so you need to use `acc?.[t.region]?.[t.sub_region]` to access it. Note that the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) is used to prevent an error from being thrown when the region does not exist yet.

```js
const items = [
    {
        region: 'EUROPE',
        sub_region: 'SOUTH_EUROPE',
        item: 'Item 1'
    },
    {
        region: 'EUROPE',
        sub_region: 'SOUTH_EUROPE',
        item: 'Item 2'
    },
    {
        region: 'EUROPE',
        sub_region: 'NORTH_EUROPE',
        item: 'Item 3'
    },
    {
        region: 'AMERICAS',
        sub_region: 'NORTH_AMERCA',
        item: 'Item 4'
    },
]

const sorted = items.reduce((acc, t) => {
    return {
        ...acc,
        [t.region]: {
            ...acc[t.region],
            [t.sub_region]: [...(acc?.[t.region]?.[t.sub_region] || []),
                              {item: t.item}],
        },
    }
}, {})

console.log(sorted)
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow up to my comment recommending a more manageable but "less clean" for loop. The reason I recommend for loop anyway is that in my experience not a lot of developers have extensive knowledge with the reduce function, especially if you have junior developers on your team. However I agree that good documentation can also provide the necessary information to maintain it. However you can't understand the function quickly when reading it which usually means uninformative variable names, too much complexity or missing documentation.

```js
const items = [{
    region: 'EUROPE',
    sub_region: 'SOUTH_EUROPE',
    item: 'Item 1'
  },
  {
    region: 'EUROPE',
    sub_region: 'SOUTH_EUROPE',
    item: 'Item 2'
  },
  {
    region: 'EUROPE',
    sub_region: 'NORTH_EUROPE',
    item: 'Item 3'
  },
  {
    region: 'AMERICAS',
    sub_region: 'NORTH_AMERCA',
    item: 'Item 4'
  },
]

const categorize = (someItems) => {
  const sorted = {}
  someItems.forEach(item => {
    if (!sorted[item.region]) sorted[item.region] = {}
    if (!sorted[item.region][item.sub_region]) sorted[item.region][item.sub_region] = []

    sorted[item.region][item.sub_region].push(item)
  })
  return sorted
}

console.log(categorize(items))
```

Comment: I appreciate the follow up Vincent. I didnt expect it to be as clean as you have presented it, nice work. I would be interested in finding out if one is more performant than the other but may keep this structure in mind depending on what type of team I am working with.

Comment: First of all thanks for the kind feedback. I let both functions run 100.000 times. My solution took about 52ms while the reduce function took about 260ms however this might be due to the way I messured. Here is a screenshot of my console as reference http://i.prnt.sc/jDTt7F2LQo_V_bQOBW-TEg.png